# CSS3 Property animation-fill-mode: What's the difference with "both" and "forwards"

Tags: css, animation

What's the difference with "animation-fill-mode: both" and "animation-fill-mode: forwards"??
In my opinion ,They all retain the computed values set by the last keyframe.Can anybody give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`animation-fill-mode: both` combines `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, and `animation-fill-mode: backwards`. When `animation-fill-mode: backwards` is specified, values from the first keyframe in the animation are applied immediately when the animation begins *even if* there is an animation-delay. If fill-mode: backwards, or both is not specified, then the first keyframe is not applied until after the animation-delay. You can read more [in the spec.](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property)

Answer (score 0):

you can see the difference from the example of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

To see the difference you need to set `animation-delay`.